# React Native template literal in this.props.navigation.navigate

Tags: react-native, react-props, template-literals

is it possible to use `template literal` in `this.props.navigation.navigate`, something like this

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("TicketBuyerDetail", {
 "firstName": this.state.firstName,
 "lastName": this.state.lastName,
 "emailUser": this.state.emailUser,
 "infoAdded": true
});
```

I try to wrote it like above but it throws an error *Unexpected Token*, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the double quotations in your params.

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('TicketBuyerDetail', {
    firstName: this.state.firstName,
    lastName: this.state.lastName,
    emailUser: this.state.emailUser,
    infoAdded: true,
});
```